# Excel Data Validation based on Multiple Selection

Tags: excel, offset, vlookup, validation

I am trying to use Excel Data Validation to calculate a users drop selection based on 3 different variables.  I was reading through this website http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html but I can't seem to work out how to do it based on multiple lists.

I know I need to use Data Validation, Lists and I think Offset but I am struggling with creating the lists.

Below is the Excel Data

[image: Excel Data]

Effectively, a drop down needs to be in B10, B11, B12.

But, Whatever Agency is chosen, only those rates should be applied in the column that pertains to that Agency.

Can someone please help with how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure which bit you need help with; getting the drop downs to work or the formula to go in cell B15 (or both). I'll answer both and hopefully we can get you where you need to be.

Getting the drop downs to work I think you may have sorted but just in case:

1. Select cell B10, click Data --> Data Valication
2. In the popup select
3. List from the Allow dropdown In Source you can click the icon and
           select the cells `=$B$1:$E$1`
4. Click the little icon again and then OK and you're good to go.

Repeat for the other drop downs. Note, if your list is on a different worksheet you need to use a named range to reference it.

As for picking up the correct rate for cell B15 this should work:

`=VLOOKUP(B11,$A$2:$G$6,MATCH($B$10,$A$1:$G$1,0),0)`

Comment: thankyou very much, the Data Validation part I had right but the VLOOKUP was quite complex but now it makes sense. Thankyou so much !!!

Comment: NOTE: I have edited the above, I had the inputs for `MATCH' the wrong way round; should have actually typed it into Excel instead of going from memory. Also don't need the +1.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some ranges on the lists you want to use for your validation.

From what I have used, the validation based on lists works vertically, not horizontally.
So column A lists your options relating to Agency and under each subsequent column you place its corresponding new set of options putting the "title" of the list in row 1 that relates to list A.

Your next drop down list needs to use validation but in the source you need to enter "=INDIRECT($B$10)" and this should then filter based on your choice in your first drop down.

Then repeat the process for your next drop down - you might be interested in This article from Microsoft which explains conditional drop down lists:

http://blogs.office.com/2009/11/24/create-conditional-drop-down-lists/